# How would you console log in Gatsby js?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

In any other environment console.log('hello world') should print in the terminal when the line of code is executed but in Gatsby Js no matter what I try or where I look to understand what's going on I'm still left confused. Could someone explain what's going on with Gatsby not allowing me to console log?

Comment: `no matter what I try` - What did you try? Can you show an example?

Comment: There's no particular reason that should not work. Are you completely sure your code is even executed? Try putting a `console.log` somewhere where you are 100% sure the code is executed.

Comment: I've tried creating another gatsby environment, did't console.log. Express js, React, plain vanilla js, typescript and react-native console log after starting the environment with npm or yarn. Gatsby is the only environment that doesn't let me console log anything. I can share my code if that helps.  https://github.com/FormidablePencil/blog-site

Comment: I've downloaded gatsby cli but neither my mac or windows console log in anything in the terminal when project is running

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Post your solution and mark your question as solved, please. Otherwise people will stumble upon your question and wonder how you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Needed to use the browser's console opposed to the terminal in which the app is running on. Came from React-Native where console logging would print in the terminal window running the app.